# Generate MongoDB database based on NodeJs models

Tags: node.js, mongodb

the database i had on atlas got deleted for inactivity and now i dont have the database schema/backup. I only have nodejs models. Is there a tool that i can use to recreate database?

I do not know what to do.

Comment: Deleted or paused due to inactivity? If the latter then you should be able to unpause it.  Separately, can you run the app? You don't need to "create the schema" before using MongoDB

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.